# Nav buttons with hover effect

Tags: css, button, navigation

I want to duplicate the style of buttons on this page http://oakespavers.com/ (left-hand side) with the same hover effect. Every time I try, only the text in the boxes are affected. I want the entire div to change colors on mouseover and keep the code really simple.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Why not inspect the element and see how they have done it. At least post the code you have tried.

Comment: I tried replicating the code but it was a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Our Blog</a>
<a href="#">Contact US</a>
​
```

CSS:

```
a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Verdana", "Geneva", "sans-serif";
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 225px;
    margin: 5px;
}
a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #75D039;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYtA8/) with an example
    ​

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! So much simpler than what I came up with. Thank you so much.